# Flex DataGridColumn id missing?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am creating a Datagrid dynamically in AS3. In MXML it is valid to write:

```
mx:DataGridColumn dataField="abc" id="testColumn"
```

in AS3 however, I can not use the property "id", it is not found. Any ideas?

```
var dgc : DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
dgc.id = "testColumn"; (NOT WORKING)
```

Thanks,
martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id is not a real property, but only a way to define the variable name in mxml. Therefore in your case the ID is "dgc".

What are you trying to achieve, by the way?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to add a summary footer to the datagrid, and the summary column needs to refer to the ID of a "real" datagrid column.
http://code.seanhess.net/?p=17